# Insert foreign keys and data in single select statement

Tags: sql, db2

I have a insert statement that looks similar to this:

```
insert into memberOf (pid, gid)
select p.pid, g.gid
from person as p,
    group as g
where (p.name, g.name) IN (
    ('person1','groupA'),
    ('person2','groupA'),
    ('person3','groupB'),    
);
```

pid and gid combined make up the primary key, and each one itself is obviously a foreign key referencing two different tables; person and group.
Now the table memberOf contains two more columns: from and until, each being a date representing the timeframe the person was or is member of the group.

Is there any way by which I could represent each resulting line in memberOf as a single line in this insert statement?

Something similar to this (just assume '1970' would be considered a valid member of DATE type):

```
insert into memberOf (pid, gid, from, until)
select p.pid, g.gid, DATE, DATE
from person as p,
    group as g
where (p.name, g.name) IN (
    ('person1','groupA','1970','2000'),
    ('person2','groupA','1970','2016'),
    ('person3','groupB','1999','2005'),    
);
```

Again I'm sure you can make two different tables, one with the foreign keys, one with the dates and then combine them somehow, but the points is to have related data be all in the same line.

Comment: You might be referring to a record where person is person1 and group should be groupA and dateFrom is 1970 and dateUntil is 2000? Is this for single record? If so, you might not want to use IN since it will give you all persons coming from groupA and groupB whether they are person1, person2 and person3 or not. It should be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding the dates to the `WHERE` clause?

Doesn't this give you what you want?

```
insert into memberOf (pid, gid, from, until)
select p.pid, g.gid, DATE, DATE
from person as p,
    group as g
where (p.name, g.name) IN (
    ('person1','groupA'),
    ('person2','groupA'),
    ('person3','groupB'),    
);
```

The data being inserted isn't from the `WHERE` it's from the `select p.pid, g.gid, DATE, DATE`

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work on DB2 for i.

```
INSERT INTO
    memberOf (pid, gid)
SELECT
    p.pid, g.gid
FROM
    TABLE(VALUES
        ('person1','groupA'),
        ('person2','groupA'),
        ('person3','groupB')
    ) AS t(person, group)
INNER JOIN
    person AS p ON p.name = t.person
INNER JOIN
    group AS g ON g.name = t.group
```